# Retrieve the JNLP file from the service

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Is there any API that returns the 'caller' .jnlp file? I am trying to create a generic installer (see below, SOURCE_JNLP) that can programatically access the JNPL used to launch the WebStart client.

```
BasicService bs = (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
String myJNLPFile = new URL(bs.getCodeBase()+ "/"+SOURCE_JNLP));
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean when you say "caller". Could you probably provide an example?

Comment: Add `SOURCE_JNLP` as a property within the JNLP.